# What is the $n$th derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$?

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate the $n$th derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$?

I think I need to use chain rule but I'm not sure.

Comment: To find an explicit formula would be tortuous. You can prove by induction it is of the form $e^{-1/x^2}P_n(x^{-1})$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$. You can even find a recursive formula for the coefficients, most probably.

Comment: Is that really what you need to find, or do you merely need to find the limiting value at $0$ of the $n$-th derivative?

Comment: I'm not even sure what is 1st derivative of it. Is it $e^{-1/x^2}$ * ${2/x^3}$?

Comment: @user88310: I wonder if you can use the Faà di Bruno formula and Bell polynomials with Lah numbers.

Comment: Errata: The degree should be $3n$ as Sami notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let
$$f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
Prove by induction that
$$f^{(n)}(x)=P_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
where $P_n$ is a polynomial with degree $3n$ and leading coefficient $2^n$ and find its recursive formula.

Comment: Ah, my bad, Sami.

Comment: Isn't f'(x) = $e^{-1/x^2}$ * ${2/x^3}$ and f''(x) = $e^{-1/x^2}$ (-6$x^{-4}$ + $\frac{4}{x^6}$)?

Comment: I'm not sure why P$_n$ is a polynomial with degree 3n!

Comment: Oh you put 1/x not x to $P_n$ so its degreee would be 6 for f''(x)!